# Trouble parsing data from SOAP call in PHP

Tags: php, html, rest, soap

I am integrating a catalog functionality to our company website that I have designed, [akserigraphics.com](http://akserigraphics.com). I have already integrated all of the `drinkware` items and many of the promotional items using REST. Now I am trying to integrate `garments` but they are coming from a different source that uses SOAP. I can make the SOAP call successfully and have checked it in SoapUI, but I can't access the contents of the object in the PHP document.

Here is the layout that I am attempting to have the SOAP data populate in PHP:

```php
<?php
foreach ($result -> listResponse as $item): ?>
  <a href="/products/garments/brands/new.era/productview.php?model=<?php echo $item->style; ?>">
    <div id="shirt_<?php print $item->style; ?>'" class="catalog-box-1 three-col-por">
      <div class="catalog-box-1-content">
        <div class="mask"></div>
        <h3><span><?php print $item->style; ?></span><br><?php print $item->productTitle; ?></h3>
        <?php $thumbpic = $item->productImage; ?>
        <img src="<?php print $thumbpic; ?>" alt="<?php print $item->productTitle; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Below is the code that I am using:

```php
<?php
$actualLink = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 48 ? (int)$_GET['per-page'] : 12;
$previous = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
$a = $page - 2;
$b = $page - 1;
$e = $page;
$c = $page + 1;
$d = $page + 2;

$findBrand = 'New Era';

try{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 900); 

    $localhostWsdlUrl="https://stage-ws.sanmar.com:8080/SanMarWebService/SanMarProductInfoServicePort?WSDL";

    $client= new SoapClient($localhostWsdlUrl, array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>true));

    //these methods used to see the wsdl methods and their types.
    //var_dump($client->__getFunctions() ); 
    //var_dump('<br/>');  
    //var_dump($client->__getTypes());

    //web service credentail 
    $arg0 = array('brandName' => $findBrand);

    $arg1 = array(
                'sanMarCustomerNumber' => '1175',
                'sanMarUserName' => '######',
                'sanMarUserPassword' => '######'
            );

    $getProductInfoByBrand = array('arg0' => $arg0, 'arg1' => $arg1 );

    //calling the GetInvoiceByInvoiceNo method.
    $result = $client->__soapCall('getProductInfoByBrand', array('getProductInfoByBrand' => $getProductInfoByBrand));
    //var_dump($result);

} catch(SoapFault $e) {
  //var_dump($e);
}

?>
```

Below is the output I am receiving:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/akswebmaster/akserigraphics.com/products/garments/brands/new.era/index.php on line 246

Running a var_dump($results); produces the following:

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["return"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["errorOccured"]=> bool(true) ["message"]=> string(34) "ERROR: User authentication failed." } }

Here is what SoapUI returns:

```html
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:getProductInfoByBrandResponse xmlns:ns2="http://impl.webservice.integration.sanmar.com/">
      <return>
        <errorOccured>false</errorOccured>
        <listResponse>
          <productBasicInfo>
            <brandName>OGIO Endurance</brandName>
            <caseSize>8</caseSize>
            <catalogColor>Cobalt</catalogColor>
            <color>Black/Silver/Cobalt</color>
            <inventoryKey>70172</inventoryKey>
            <keywords>ogio, duffel, multi-sport duffel, duffel bag, sports duffel, sports bag, shoe compartment, shoe pocket, shoe-pocket, shoe-compartment,ventilated shoe compartment, adjustable shoulder strap, side pocket, sweat-resistant carrying handle, accessory
              pocket, high visibility liner, high visibility,</keywords>
            <pieceWeight>1.6458</pieceWeight>
            <productDescription>Unleash the adrenaline inside you with this intuitively designed multi-sport duffel. 420D diamond rip stop/300D poly diamond rip stop/600D poly Large main compartment Ventilated shoe compartment Secondary zippered side pocket Adjustable shoulder
              strap with ventilated shoulder pad Sweat-resistant soft touch molded carrying handle Zippered front accessory pocket Durable, abrasion-resistant base Dimensions: 10.5"h x 20"w x 9.25"d Capacity: 2,500 cu. in./41L Weight 1.2 lbs./0.5kg Bags
              not intended for use by children 12 and under.</productDescription>
            <productStatus>CloseOut</productStatus>
            <productTitle>CLOSEOUT OGIO ENDURANCE - 2.0 Duffel 412030</productTitle>
            <size>OSFA</size>
            <sizeIndex>3</sizeIndex>
            <style>
              412030
            </style>
            <uniqueKey>701723</uniqueKey>
          </productBasicInfo>
          <productImageInfo>
            <brandLogoImage>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/catalog/images/ogioenduranceheader.jpg</brandLogoImage>
            <colorProductImage>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/catalog/images/imglib/catl/2012/f12/412030_BlackSilverCobalt_Flat_GA13.jpg</colorProductImage>
            <colorProductImageThumbnail>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/cache/altview/imglib/catl/2012/f12/412030_BlackSilverCobalt_Flat_GA13.jpg</colorProductImageThumbnail>
            <colorSquareImage>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/swatch/gifs/ogio_blueprint.gif</colorSquareImage>
            <colorSwatchImage>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/catalog/images/412030sw.jpg</colorSwatchImage>
            <productImage>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/catalog/images/412030.jpg</productImage>
            <specSheet>https://www.apparelvideos.com/images/specsheet/pdf/specsheet/412030_specsheet.pdf</specSheet>
            <thumbnailImage>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/catalog/images/412030TN.jpg</thumbnailImage>
            <titleImage/>
            <frontModel>https://cdnl.sanmar.com/imglib/mresjpg/2012/f12/412030_BlackSilverCobalt_Flat_GA13.jpg</frontModel>
            <backModel/>
            <sideModel/>
            <backFlat/>
            <frontFlat/>
            <threeQModel/>
          </productImageInfo>
          <productPriceInfo>
            <casePrice>24.6</casePrice>
            <caseSalePrice>12.28</caseSalePrice>
            <dozenPrice>26.6</dozenPrice>
            <dozenSalePrice>12.28</dozenSalePrice>
            <piecePrice>28.6</piecePrice>
            <pieceSalePrice>12.28</pieceSalePrice>
            <priceCode>R</priceCode>
            <priceText>OSFA</priceText>
            <saleEndDate>2020-06-29</saleEndDate>
            <saleStartDate>2016-07-23</saleStartDate>
          </productPriceInfo>
        </listResponse>
```

I have been searching for several days and can't seem to identify what I am doing wrong. I also contacted the 'Integration Support' at the company that the SOAP call is from and got following response

> Unfortunately, I do not know what you would need to accomplish that, we do not do any coding.

I am only a beginner when it comes to PHP so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error means that `$result->ListResponse` is not an array that you can loop over. So you need to check what it actually is. What kind of variable does `_soapCall` return and what properties does it have? Try a `var_dump($result);` to give yourself a clue, unless the method's documentation tells you

Comment: soooo.. looking at your edited post w/ `vardump`, it looks like authentication is the issue?

Comment: Apparently the php code provided by the api vendor had the wrong WSDL in it. $localhostWsdlUrl="https:// ***stage-*** ws.sanmar.com:8080/SanMarWebService/SanMarProductInfoServicePort?WSDL"; The correct WSDL doesn't have the stage- in it. However, I'm still receiving this message > Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/akswebmaster/akserigraphics.com/products/garments/brands/new.era/index.php on line 246

Comment: So after you changed the WSDL, did `var_dump($results);` produce anything different? I doubt that changing the WSDL will alter the fact that you haven't authenticated with the server

Comment: After changing the WSDL it no longer shows an authentication error. Other than that it doesn't give me any information. The page shows the error that I listed in my previous comment but that is quite a ways further down in the page code. What should var_dump($results) show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently there were two issues. The first issue was that the WSDL that I was using was the testing one instead of the production one.

```
https://stage-ws.sanmar.com:8080/SanMarWebService/SanMarProductInfoServicePort?WSDL
```

should have been

```
https://ws.sanmar.com:8080/SanMarWebService/SanMarProductInfoServicePort?WSDL
```

After fixing that I was facing a new problem of the server timing out. After weeks of frustration and hundreds of variations I was able to get a knowledgeable IT guy on the phone from the vendor. It turns out that my call was returning so much data that it was causing the connection to timeout. His solution was for me to download a csv file of all of the products and load it into a database on my server from which I can then run SQL commands to. I will be doing this next week and can finally get this project wrapped up.